# issues appending jsons to vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So i have this json coming back from my server:

```
[
  [
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;6.00"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_price",
    "&Acirc;&pound;60.00"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;8.00"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_price",
    "&Acirc;&pound;120.00"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_price",
    "&Acirc;&pound;240.00"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;3.20"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;2.86"
  ],
  [
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;2.50"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "Later Owl Ticket"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "Later Owl Ticket+Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "Later Owl + Chance For VIP Upgrade"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "VIP Ticket"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "VIP Ticket + Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "Skydeck Package"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "5 Person Skydeck Table"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "7 Person Skydeck Table"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "10 Person Skydeck Table"
  ]
]
```

Now what im wanting is my ajax call to put these into a table. The first fees and price goes with the first ticket_desc. Each and everytime! The code i have the append to table code. ITs getting the price, fees and description into vars. How do i go about doing this?

This is how i was attempting to do this

```
success: function(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var section = json[i][0];
      if (section == "ticket_desc") {
        var ticket = json[i][1];
        debugger;
      }
```

However i ran into issues where the ticket_desc isn't matching up, However i didnt think it would work!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: which code are you talking about sir?

Comment: The one i totally missed adding! One second :)

Comment: Not all of the elements of json have ticket_desc, that's why it is not matching. Try adding it all of the elements like this:

[
    "formatted_sum_fees",
    "&Acirc;&pound;2.50"
  ],
  [
    "ticket_desc",
    "Later Owl Ticket"
  ],

Comment: If you have an opportunity to restructure the returned JSON, I'd take it over trying to working with a structure like this

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what the eventual data format is supposed to be, and there are probably many different ways of processing your json, but let's try:

I'd prefer an array of objects that have a `description` and `fee` property. For example:

```
var ticket = {
  description: "Later Owl Ticket",
  fee: "&Acirc;&pound;6.00"
};
```

Now, if I understand your data correctly, the *order* of the array in the json determines the matches between fees and descriptions.

If this is the case, and you can be certain there are no missing values, a straightforward solution could be:

```
var nrOfTickets = json.length / 2;
var fees = json.slice(0, nrOfTickets);         // First half
var descriptions = json.slice(nrOfTickets);    // Second half

var tickets = descriptions.map(function(descrArr, index) {
  var feeArr = fees[index];
  return {
    description: descrArr[1],
    fee: feeArr[1]
  };
});
```

If you want to make it shorter, you could do:

```
var tickets = [];
for (var i = 0, l = json.length / 2; i < l; i += 1) {
  tickets.push({
    fee: json[i][1],
    description: json[i+l][1]
  });
};
```

If the fees and descriptions are scrambled, you can sort them like so:

```
var descriptions = [],
    fees = [];

json.forEach(function(arr) {
  if (arr[1] === "ticket_desc") {
    descriptions.push(arr);
  } else {
    fees.push(arr)
  };
});
```